# Sequential String Replace Calls not working as Expected in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
let data = "${name} {complexion}";

console.log(data.replace("${name}","I am ").replace("${complexion}","Black"));
```

I am getting the following output:

```
I am  {complexion}
```

This is weird, this works out of the box in other languages like Java.

I am supposed to get back:

```
I am Black
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: You missed the $ sign before `{complexion}`  in data string

Comment: you have a typo there is no $ in front of the {complexion}

Comment: Oh yea, that's true...Thank you